# How precise is the CC1101

Tags: radio

I was experimenting with CC1101 module (E07-M1101D) and noticed that the base frequency seems to be around 14 kHz lower than programmed one. It is rather constant, not a proportional value.

Is this normal behavior, or did I mess something up? I was not able to find anything about that in the data sheet.

EDIT
For central frequency at 433.92 MHz it is 32.25 ppm if calculated correctly.

EDIT
Adding the error compensation in the places where crystal frequency is used to calculate register values helps.

Comment: at which center frequency is that? How many parts-per-million of the center frequency is 14 kHz?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i've updated the relative error: base_frequency/error*100000

Comment: you've missed a 0 there!

Comment: How are you **measuring** the frequency? How do you know that the error is not in your measurement?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson rtl-sdr, but according to the `kal` tool and comparision to local GSM carier, it had low error of -0.056ppm

Answer (score 2):

The CC1101 is totally dependent on the crystal oscillator for accuracy.

Presumably one could graft an off-the-shelf 0.5ppm oscillator module on there in place of the cheap crystal and achieve commensurate improvement in accuracy, if perhaps not jitter.

Crystals are often specified at +/-50ppm or so with optimum load capacitance values. If it's an inexpensive module they may not be using the most accurate crystals on the market or have bothered to get the load caps exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

32 ppm isn't excellent – most crystals don't get better than 20 ppm.  Reliably better than 10 ppm is usually the domain of temperature-compensated oscillators.

For an undisciplined oscillator, some 30 ppm error aren't rare. So, this might be simply within the accuracy you can achieve given your oscillator's properties.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers said, the CC1101 depends on the crystal's frequency. There is another factor that affects this frequency - the load capacitors of the crystals, along with the parasitic capacitance of the pads and traces of the oscillator circuit.

You can compensate this offset by changing the 3 freq registers.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the manual, you have two default options:

- Either a crystal oscillator of 26MHz with 40ppm = +/1.04kHz.
- Or a RC oscillator of 34.7MHz with +/-1% after calibration = +/-347kHz.

This gives the accuracy of the intermediate frequency, not the carrier 433.92MHz. The frequency error will probably get multiplied somewhat there, so 32ppm sounds about right.

If that's enough to pass radio conformance, that's another story. +/- 14kHz on the carrier sounds like something which might fail occupied carrier width requirements.

Comment: Your numbers are a bit off. 40ppm of 26MHz is 1040Hz.

Comment: @LiorBilia Indeed, thanks. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The RF frequencies from the CC1101 are determined by **two** things: the crystal frequency and the IC configuration (in the registers).

Here's the tricky thing: the CC1101 is spec'd to use *either* a 26 MHz crystal *or* a 27 MHz crystal, depending on which harmonics you are trying to optimize around.

The register configuration values are generally calculated by TI's [SmartRF Studio](https://www.ti.com/tool/SMARTRFTM-STUDIO) software. One of the fields in SmartRF Studio asks for the crystal frequency. Then it goes from there.

Perhaps your settings were assuming a different crystal frequency that was actually loaded onto your dev board?